# Joining Two Tables in Python Based on Condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, join, merge

I have two tables in pandas:

df1: Containing User IDs and IP_Addresses for 150K users.

```
|---------------|---------------|  
|    User_ID    |   IP_Address  |
|---------------|---------------|  
|      U1       |   732758368.8 |
|      U2       |   350311387.9 |
|      U3       |   2621473820  |
|---------------|---------------|
```

df2: Containing IP Address range and country it belongs to, 139K records

```
|---------------|-----------------|------------------|  
|    Country    | Lower_Bound_IP  |  Upper_Bound_IP  |
|---------------|-----------------|------------------|  
|   Australia   |   1023787008    |    1023791103    |
|   USA         |   3638734848    |    3638738943    |
|   Australia   |   3224798976    |    3224799231    |
|   Poland      |   1539721728    |    1539721983    |
|---------------|-----------------|------------------|
```

My objective is to create a country column in df1 such that IP_Address of df1 lies between the range of Lower_Bound_IP and Upper_Bound_IP of that country in df2.

```
|---------------|---------------|---------------|   
|    User_ID    |   IP_Address  |    Country    |
|---------------|---------------|---------------|   
|      U1       |   732758368.8 |   Indonesia   |
|      U2       |   350311387.9 |   Australia   |
|      U3       |   2621473820  |   Albania     |
|---------------|---------------|---------------|
```

My first approach was to do a cross join (cartesian product) of the two tables and then filter to the relevant records. However, a cross join using pandas.merge() is not feasible, since it will create 21 billion records. The code crashes every time. Could you please suggest an alternative solution which is feasible?

Comment: Are the IP_Address ranges comprehensive? i.e., are there IP_Address values in `df1` for which you'd expect `Country` to be null?

Comment: @cmaher I will assume for now that the ranges are comprehensive so that there will be no null country for any user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure how to deal with doing this with pandas.where, but with `numpy.where` you can do

```
idx = numpy.where((df1.Ip_Address[:,None] >= df2.Lower_Bound_IP[None,:]) 
    & (df1.IP_Address[:,None] <= df2.Upper_Bound_IP[None,:]))[1]
df1["Country"] = df2.Country[idx]
```

`numpy.where` gives the indices where the given condition is True. `&` corresponds to 'and', and the whole `[:,None]` bit adds a dummy axis where `None` is located. This makes sure that for each `User_ID`, the indices in `df2` is found where the `IP_Address` is within the range. `[1]` gives the indices in `df2` where the condition is True.
This will break down if there's overlap in your ranges in df2.

This might still cause you to have memory issues, but you could add a loop such that you do this comparison in batches. E.g.

```
batch_size = 1000
n_batches = df1.shape[0] // batch_size
# Integer division rounds down, so if the number
# of User_ID's is not divisable by the batch_size,
# we need to add 1 to n_batches
if n_batches * batch_size < df1.shape[0]:
    n_batches += 1
indices = []
for i in range(n_batches):
    idx = numpy.where((df1.Ip_Address[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size,None]
            >= df2.Lower_Bound_IP[None,:]) & 
            (df1.IP_Address[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size,None] 
            <= df2.Upper_Bound_IP[None,:]))[1]
    indices.extend(idx.tolist())

df1["Country"] = df2.Country[np.asarray(indices)]
```

Comment: It works like charm. Thank you so much. The batch calculation is really helpful in my case. Substantially eases load on the memory.